# MVC 4 Client Side Field validation for a list of fields (instead of fields as members of a class)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am a long time backend .Net developer who is new to web application development.   I am using MVC 4, Razor, EF 5, and I have a basic understanding on how to make a routine DB driven MVC 4 site with these tools.

I need to create a custom form capability for a workflow scenario.  I have the entire code-first schema designed and classes for different formfield types, and formvalue type.

The model that will be passed to a view will be a form class with a list of formvalues, which contain form field specifications.   So the view will have to iterate through the form fields and dynamically choose what editors to use and so on.

My problem is that this prevents me from using any data annotation for client side validation.  And every place I find advice on custom validation assumes (not surprisingly) that all the fields are members of a class.  Whereas, in this case, all the fields are on a list.

My goal is to end up with validation messages on each field and a validation summary as you would normally have if the view was simply bound to an annotated class.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?   Thanks in advance.

Imagine view logic that has the following:

```
@foreach (var fieldvalue in Model.FormFieldValues) {

    // Logic that chooses the appropriate editor based on typeof(fieldvalue.FormField)
    // Binds the editor to fieldvalue.Value
    // Validation specs are contained in the Formfield obtained by fieldValue.FormField
    // And my problem is setting up the validation without the aid of the normal method 
    //   of data annotation or class level custom validation.
}
```

and the fieldvalue class looks like this:

```
public class FormFieldValue : EboEntity 
{ 
    public string Value { get; set; } 

    [Required] 
    public int FormFieldId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual FormField FormField { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
}
```

And imagine that the FormField object has fields such as Required, Maxlength, and so on, depending on the kind of field it is (i. e. FormFieldText would be a subclass of FormField)

ANSWER:

Ok, you can tell I am new at MVC.

The answer to my question is that the specific editors take htmlAttributes which can control validation.  So in the case where one of my formfields is a required textfield of stringlenth(10), I can invoke the editor as follows:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NoTexty, new { 
                                                        required = true,
                                                        maxlength = 10,
                                                        placeholder = "Texty"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoTexty)
    </div>
```

but in my case the htmlAddtributes won't be hard coded, but rather they will come from the fields in the formvalue.FormField object.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time on this.   But I will leave this here for any other newbies like me.

Comment: Realistically, your models should be a representation of your DB classes. Otherwise, how do you plan to put specific validation on things when the model itself is dynamic?

Comment: Okay, can you post your model?

Comment: It would be really beneficial and help you get more answers if you could post something to do with your model/logic you currently have in place :)

Comment: I've added your model to your question. That should give people more information to go from :)

Comment: I deleted my comments to reduce the noise.  All the info is in the edit question above.

Comment: I figured it out.  See the edited question.

Comment: Great stuff, if you found an answer, post it as an answer and accept it :)